# Cannot set property 'width' of undefined

Tags: html, class, properties, undefined

```
function size(){
for(i=0; i<squares; i++){
    document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += "<div class='squareCell' id='objetive"+i+"'></div>";
}
document.getElementsByClassName('squareCell').style.width="300px";
document.getElementsByClassName('squareCell').style.height="300px";}
```

Still getting "Cannot set property 'width' of undefined" and dont know why. I'm not trying to just solve this, I want to learn what is exactly happening here.

Greetings.

Comment: You are defining the function there, but not actually calling it (at least not in the little code you posted). So it looks like you try to define with, before you run the function adding the class name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `getElementsByClassName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a array object

If you have one class name `squareCell` then you can do it by defining the 0 th index like this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('squareCell')[0].style.width="300px";
document.getElementsByClassName('squareCell')[0].style.height="300px";
```

If you want to do with multiple use loop

```
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName('squareCell');
 for(var i=0; i< x.length;i++){
    x[i].style.width = "300px";
    x[i].style.height = "300px";
 }
```

**OR**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('squareCell');
  Array.from(elements).forEach(function(element) {
      element.style.height = '50px';
      element.style.width = '50px';
  });
```

```js
function makeSquare(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('squareCell');
  Array.from(elements).forEach(function(element) {
      element.style.height = '50px';
      element.style.width = '50px';
  });
}
```

```css
.squareCell{
    background-color: #ff00ff;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="makeSquare()">Make Square</button>
<br/>
<div class="squareCell">Test1</div>
<div class="squareCell">Test2</div>
<div class="squareCell">Test3</div>
<div class="squareCell">Test4</div>
<div class="squareCell">Test5</div>
<div class="squareCell">Test6</div>
```